# Nginx fastcgi_cache shoud be impact on static files?

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, caching, server

I have an application using Laravel as backend (API) and Angular as frontend. All in the same project.

I have configured my Nginx to serve both, backend and frontend. To my backend I set `fastcgi_cache` and it works well in most cases, but sometimes frontend doesn't works as expected and I realize that `fastcgi_cache` is impacting it, generating a kind of cache to my static files too.

The API endpoint returns the correct data, even using cache, but the frontend can't display it until I clean the NGINX/FastCGI cache. The places where information should be displayed on the page are left blank. Am I missing something?

Below is my configuration:

```
# FastCGI cache zone
fastcgi_cache_path /tmp/nginx_cache/my-app levels=1:2 keys_zone=MYAPP:100m inactive=60m;

upstream php_backend {
  keepalive 100;
  server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

server {
  underscores_in_headers on;

  listen [::]:80;
  listen 80;

  server_name mydomain.com;

  root /var/www/my-app/public;
  index index.php;

  add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
  add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
  add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
  add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

  # security
  include nginxconfig.io/security.conf;

  # additional config
  include nginxconfig.io/general.conf;

  # FastCGI cache settings for PHP
  set $skip_cache 0;

  # POST requests and urls with a query string should always go to PHP
  if ($request_method = POST) {
    set $skip_cache 1;
  }

  # Dont't cache when there is a query string (e.g. ?search=query)
  if ($query_string != "") {
    set $skip_cache 1;
  }
  
  # Frontend
  # HERE IS WHERE THE FONTEND APPLICATION IS RUNNING
  location /web {
    alias /var/www/my-app/web;

    try_files $uri $uri/ @web;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location ~* /index.html|.*\.json$ {
      add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
      expires -1;
    }

    # Cache static files
    location ~* \.(css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2)$ {
      expires 30d;
      add_header Cache-Control "public, no-transform";
    }

    # No cache JS files
    location ~* \.(js)$ {
      expires off;
      add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
      add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
      if_modified_since off;
      etag off;
    }
  }

  location @web {
    rewrite /web/(.*)$ /web/index.html?args;
  }

  # phpmyadmin
  location ^~ /bd_app_fnon {
    satisfy all;

    include includes/fnon-allowed-ips;

    deny all;

    auth_basic "Admin Login";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/pma_passes/bd_app_fnon;

    # logging
    access_log /var/log/nginx/phpmyadmin/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/phpmyadmin/error.log warn;

    alias /var/www/bd_app_fnon;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /bd_app_fnon/index.php?args;
    index index.php;

    include uwsgi_params;

    location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(?:\/bd_app_fnon\/)(.+\.php)(.*)$;

      try_files $uri =404;

      fastcgi_pass fnon_php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/nginx/html$fastcgi_script_name;
      include fastcgi_params;

      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    }
  }

  # Cache utils
  location ^~ /cache/opcache {
    satisfy all;

    include includes/fnon-allowed-ips;

    deny all;

    auth_basic "Admin Login";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/pma_passes/cache_dash;

    alias /var/www/opcache-dash;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /cache/opcache/index.php?args;
    index index.php;

    include uwsgi_params;

    location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(?:\/cache/opcache\/)(.+\.php)(.*)$;

      try_files $uri =404;

      fastcgi_pass fnon_php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/nginx/html$fastcgi_script_name;
      include fastcgi_params;

      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    }
  }

  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
  }

  # Deny .htaccess and other hidden files.
  location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
  }

  # PHP-FPM configuration
  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
      return 404;
    }

    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

    include fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass fnon_php;

    fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
    fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;

    # Cache settings
    fastcgi_cache MYAPP;
    fastcgi_cache_valid 200 60m;
    fastcgi_cache_methods GET HEAD;
    fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
    add_header X-FastCGI-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

    fastcgi_cache_use_stale updating error timeout invalid_header http_500;
    fastcgi_cache_lock on;

    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
  }
}
```

I'll appreciate if someone could help me. Thanks!